# MVC4 and Modernizr.Load produces flickering when conditionally adding datepicker

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, modernizr

I have an MVC4 project and am having problems with Modernizr. I want to test to see if the html input type date is supported. If not then load kendoUI (similar to jquery-UI) to display all instances where I have used input type of date as a datepicker control.
I am using the script below to load my kendo css and js files only when the input type of date is not supported.

```
<script>
    Modernizr.load({
        test: Modernizr.inputtypes.date,
        nope: ['/Content/Kendo-styles/kendo.common.min.css',
            '/Content/Kendo-styles/kendo.default.min.css',
            '/Scripts/kendo/kendo.web.min.js'],
        complete: function () {
            $('input[type=date]').kendoDatePicker({
                format: "dd/MM/yyyy"
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

I placed this in the scripts section on my page (not the _Layout/master but at the next level down). It works but I get flickering. It seems to load my scripts and then show my page before running the complete function and thus shows a textbox first and then approx. after half a second renders the datepicker in its place.

If I remove the complete function and add the following script to my document ready function it sometimes fails. In this case I can see (in browser developer tools - network) that kendo scripts have been downloaded but have not yet executed and thus the kendodatepicker is not recognised. In this case I can only presume that the document ready will run before Modernizer has completed. I this correct? Below is my document ready code.

```
$(function () {    
    if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
        $('input[type=date]').kendoDatePicker({
            format: "dd/MM/yyyy",
        });            
    }
}
```

Does anyone know of a solution to this or I am doing something stupid..

Answer (score 0):

The half second is from the fact it has to download 3 files then run the function .

I am an advocate of preloading the CSS (it's lightweight) and since you are using mvc4 you can add it to a bundle and it won't add any additional requests in production

That will make it quicker